# fatal: .git/index: unable to map index file: Invalid argument

Tags: git, command-line

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYx0l.png)

I'm getting this error when trying to git add -A on a new project I just started.

I have my folder structure laid out properly so I'm not sure why it's giving me this error, I've never gotten it before.

Comment: Please share your folder structure and anything that can help someone reproduce the error.